# обработка динамически-добавленных элементов jquery

Tags: jquery

Доброй ночи. 
Использую плагин поиска текста  `jquery-searcher`

```
    $(".table_data_choose_setup_geo_user").searcher({
        itemSelector: ".link_on_choose_many_type_setup_geo_user",
        textSelector: "",
        inputSelector: "#search_city",
    });
```

Только вот элемент `table_data_choose_setup_geo_user` у меня появляется динамически, через ajax.

Тут нужно плагин редачить на метод `on` или можно вызвать как-то по-другому ?
Спасибо !

Comment: через метод _on_ нельзя. можно вызвать этот код сразу в месте где ты вставляешь полученные элементы